# WF 4.5 State Machine: Jump to a state

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have a WPF based UI which has a navigation bar. The UI uses a WCF service with a State Machine Workflow. The WPF application is a data capture wizard sort of application. As the user goes through different states the Navigation bar shows the states(user journey or breadcrumb). At any point the user can click on any of the previously visited states to Navigate back to the state.

Using WF4, is it possible to Jump to any state without having a Transition? Another scenario is that I do not want to use the Persistence and just store the "Last State Name". Later when the user wants to resume the workflow, I just want to instantiate a new instance of the workflow and jump to the State using the stored "Last State Name" and resume the workflow.

Thanks.

I found this which is exactly what I am after but since it was posted in 2011, was wondering if there is anything new released to do the same.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Workflow-233b5e3c#content

Comment: Jumping from one state (directly) to another state without a transition connecting them would not be possible. You can write your transitions/triggers/etc so that it evaluates if necessary information is set and will automatically advance without needing to wait for input, which could make it auto advance to a point where it gets stuck...  See also this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464894/wf4-state-machine-bookmarks/  and this MSDN article on custom instance store https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee829481(v=vs.110).aspx